# Creating an egg file generates only EGG-INFO folder

Tags: python, setup.py, egg

I have a python file named `file_processor.py`. I would like to create an egg file out of this python file to use it in another projects. My `setup.py` file looks as following:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "file_processor",
    version = "0.5",
    packages = find_packages()
)
```

And I run this script with the following command:

```
python setup.py bdist_egg
```

This command generates 3 folders, namely: `build, dist, file_processor.egg-info`. My `.egg` file is located in the `dist` folder. However, if I change its extension from `.egg` to `.zip` to see the contents, I find only one folder which is `EGG-INFO`, and not the actual python file. An so, if I try to add that `.egg` file into my project path and import `file_processor` module, python throws an error that `no module named file_processor found.` What am I doing wrong here? **Note**: I got the information for generating egg files from [this link](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/12/python-101-easy_install-or-how-to-create-eggs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wheel files are generally preferred over eggs these days.

Regardless, I would guess that you don't have the `file_processor.py` in a separate directory and you have it in the same directory as the setup.py, it needs to be in it's own directory.

You should also include a `__init__.py` in that directory, inside the file you can put

`from .file_processor import *`

This will import all the functions from your file into the package so you can use them.

This tutorial is quite good if you're looking for more information https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html